# Обращение или член предложения

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, будьте добры, стоит ли ставить запятую в этом предложении?

> Идите быстрее(,) вы двое.

Answer (score 2):

*Идите быстрее, **вы двое**.*

Сочетание ***вы двое*** является обращением и обособляется.

Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=126#pp126

5. Личные местоимения ты и вы, как правило, выступают не в роли обращения, а в роли подлежащего: Простите, мирные долины, и вы, знакомых гор вершины, и вы, знакомые леса! (П.). **Но в ряде случаев они могут выступать и в роли обращения:**

1) **сами по себе:** Ступай за шестым — ты! (Т.);  Цыц, ты! Она тебе больше не слуга (М. Г.); Ну, вы! Вставайте… (М. Г.); Ну, ты, шевелись, а то прикладом огрею! (Н. О.);  «Тише, вы!» — крикнула Феня (Ант.);